# How to get Screen Shot / Screen Capture from Web user on MVC site?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, webclient, screenshot

I've seen a few different apps that allow users to take screen shots on their PC and then the utility will automatically upload the image to the web server.  I'd like to incorporate this type of functionality into a new MVC site.

I could certainly just allow the user to upload their own image, but it'd be cleaner if they could click `Capture Screen Shot` and the image would be uploaded automatically.

My team is using ASP.NET MVC2 with a SQL back end database.  We are certainly willing to look into 3rd party components (activeX based, etc.) that will allow us to achieve this.

#### update....

Google does something similar with their report a bug feature.  So not unheard of...

Comment: I think you need some type of plugin, Flash/Silverlight, to get that functionality. I don't think this can done with plain o'l HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: You can't take a screenshot of a PC even using Flash or Silverlight. The only thing you can do is to take a screenshot of a page. The only way to implement this is to create plugins for browsers.

Comment: Like the OP said, it will take a utility to do this. Something running on the actual computer that can upload an image. You've really got two questions: 1) how do I capture and upload an image from WPF/C++/whatever client program I want to make, and 2) how do I accept an image upload in MVC.

Comment: Have any of you guys looked at Google's report a bug feature?

Comment: I think, what you're looking for is a screenshot of how a particular "page" has rendered in the client's browser?

Comment: ActiveX? Seriously? There are really people who actually consider using this IE-only crap?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Solving requirements sometimes requires you to use technology that you'd rather not.  This question exists to figure out how to do it the best way.  Obviously if ActiveX can be avoided, I'll be even happier.

Comment: There is a nice solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wel, Now that i've understood what you're lookin for..  Try these..

[10 Free Website Thumbnail Generation Services](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/)

[Web Snapr](http://www.websnapr.com/)

[thumbalizr](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)

[Shrink The Web](http://www.shrinktheweb.com/)

[Web Screen Capture](http://www.webscreencapture.com/)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the links.  Unfortunately, the application I'm hoping to allow this to occur in is an Intranet based application with some government regulated security requirements.  I don't think any of these will work out, but thanks!

Comment: @RSolberg: Oh.. :( Wel then.. I guess you could search for something that's open source and re-host that as a service within your intranet.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've seen this work is through a java applet (it's how it's done in the youtrack application)

I managed to find an applet at sourceforge that at the least allow direct pasting of clipboard images...   http://supa.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Also - try http://peepshot.com - a more mordern alternative to the ones Robin Maben mentioned...

Comment: Its a local app running within our firewalls.  Not sure this would work... Thanks for the link though.